# Check the "grant_type" parameter

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am using `OAuth 2.0` for authorization according to this documentation :(https://developers.vendhq.com/documentation/oauth.html#oauth) and having this error:

> "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"grant_type\" parameter."

**Request**

Method : **POST**

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

URL : https://{domain_prefix}.vendhq.com/api/1.0/token
```

**Parameters :**

```
code          = {code}

client_id     = {app_id}

client_secret = {app_secret}

grant_type    = authorization_code

redirect_uri  = {redirect_uri}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [RFC6749, section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3), the encoded body of a POST request should look like `code={code}&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`.

Example:

> grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient%2Eexample%2Ecom%2Fcb&client_id=CLIENT_ID_1234&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET

Do not forget to encode the redirect Uri: `http://foo.bar/` => `http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.bar%2F`

Concerning the authentication error, it may be because the authorization server does not support client secret in post requests or your client is not allowed to use it (public client).
In this case, try to add the Authorization header with basic authentication scheme.
The value of this header is `Basic {ENCODED_AUTHENTICATION}` with `{ENCODED_AUTHENTICATION} =base64(client_id + ':' + client_secret)`

With this header, the `client_id` and `client_secret` in the post request have to be removed. Your request parameters become `code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`.

Comment: I was not encoding the uri. Thanks for giving me the right direction now i am getting another error

**{ "error": "invalid_client", "error_description": "Client authentication failed" }**

Comment: Really thanks for your help :) The issue was My code was expiring after 10 min. According to the documentation (This code is a short-lived object (10 min.). But really your guidance really helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to check the URL to which you are attempting to send your POST to.  The service that you are attempting to contact does not exist or is currently unavailable.